# What to do with GND of differential mode signals?

Tags: signal, ground, differential, output, input

Let us say I have 2 modules. First module gives a differential signal output on a pair of wires while the second module takes the differential signal input.

When I connect the differential signal wires between the modules do I need to connect the GNDs of the two modules together also?

Comment: That depends on the common mode rating of the components.

Comment: What modules would they be?

Comment: @Justme I am just assuming any hypothetical modules.. let us say a DAC differential output and a op-amp based differential input amplifier.

Comment: @scico111 Well obviously the question cannot be answered for any hypotetical module. It depends on the module!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, yes you do need to connect a common ground between these modules.
The receiver hardware on the 'input' module will have a 'maximum common-mode' voltage spec for its inputs which you need to ensure is not exceeded,  and this voltage is measured with reference to ground.
Of you don't connect Ground between the 2 modules you don't know what this common-mode voltage will be potentially resulting in the receiving module incorrectly interpreting the differential signal and/or suffering some damage.

Comment: Does it mean any noise on the Ground connection will be transferred between the modules? If 'yes' then it will defeat our purpose of differential signalling. Pls correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: Any 'noise on the ground connection' will be common- mode noise. Your receiver will have a common-mode rejection spec probably -90dB or better - so this noise will be ignored.